# How to integrate this function with cos and sin

Tags: integration

I'm trying to do the following:

$$\int \cos(wt)w\sin(wt+\phi) \,\mathrm{d}t$$

I can't figure what to do here. I can't do integration by parts because of the $\phi$. Any ideas?

Comment: begin by using the addition identity on the sine function. Then this integral will yield to the usual techniques.

Comment: Note that $\cos(a) \sin(b) = (\sin(a+b)-\sin(a-b))/2$.

Comment: got it, that works

Comment: You could express it all with complex exponential functions. The integrand is $\frac{w}{4i}(e^{iwt}+e^{-iwt})(e^{\phi}e^{iwt}-e^{-\phi}e^{-iwt})$. At the end this might leave you with the issue of how to translate back to real functions, but that is not insurmountable.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW

$$\eqalign{
  & \int {w\cos wt\sin \left( {wt + \phi } \right)dt}  = \cr 
  & \int {w\cos wt\left( {\sin wt\cos \phi  + \cos wt\sin \phi } \right)dt} =  \cr 
  & \cos \phi \int {w\cos wt\sin wtdt}  + \sin \phi \int {w{{\cos }^2}wtdt}  = \cr 
  & \frac{{\cos \phi }}{2}\int {w\sin 2wtdt}  + \frac{{\sin \phi }}{2}\int {w\left( {1 + \cos 2wt} \right)dt}  = \cr 
  & w\left\{ {\frac{{\sin \phi }}{2}\left( {\frac{{2t + \sin 2wt}}{2}} \right) - \frac{{\cos \phi }}{2}\left( {\frac{{\sin 2wt}}{2}} \right)} \right\} + C \cr} $$